# Инвертирование направления сортировки при сортировке по разным столбцам

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Мне помогли найти сортировку для ttk.Treeview(вопрос: [Как реализовать сортировку в БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099775/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94/1100346#1100346)), но заметил небольшую неприятность в этом коде. Всё работает замечательно, но хотелось бы реализовать одну функцию после нажатия на столбец.

### Порядок выполнения действий

1. Нажать на любой столбец для сортировки
2. Нажать на другой столбец для сортировки
3. Опять нажать на первый столбец для сортировки

---

### Фактический результат

На первом выбранном столбце происходит сортировка в обратном порядке

---

### Ожидаемый результат

Хотелось бы чтоб сортировка при нажатии на первый выбранный столбец опять начиналась с обычной, а потом уже обратная

---

### Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(frame)
columns = ("one","two","three")
tree1["columns"]= columns
tree1.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree1.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
tree1.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.pack()

columns = ("one","two","three")

tree1.heading("#0", command=lambda : treeview_sort_column0(tree1, "#0", False))

for col in columns:
    tree1.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: \
                     treeview_sort_column(tree1, _col, False))


tree1.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
tree1.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)

tree1.insert('', tk.END, text='2', values=('3','1','2'))
tree1.insert('', tk.END, text='1', values=('2','3','1'))
tree1.insert('', tk.END, text='3', values=('1','2','3'))



def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
               treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))


def treeview_sort_column0(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.item(k)["text"], k) for k in tv.get_children()] #Display column #0 cannot be set
    l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column0(tv, col, not reverse))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно запоминать, по какой колонке была сортировка в прошлый раз. Если была та же, то менять направление сортировки, если другая - то сортировать в прямом направлении.

```
prev_column = None


def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    global prev_column

    # Если была другая колонка, то делаем прямую сортировку
    if prev_column != col:    
        reverse = False

    prev_column = col

    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))


def treeview_sort_column0(tv, col, reverse):
    global prev_column

    if prev_column != col:
        reverse = False

    prev_column = col

    l = [(tv.item(k)["text"], k) for k in tv.get_children()] #Display column #0 cannot be set
    l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column0(tv, col, not reverse))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!