# Как реализовать сортировку БД таблицы tkinter по заголовку

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3, treeview

Проблема - lambda не видит созданную функцию treeview_sort_column, пытался вынести функцию в класс main, но тогда появляется проблема с ключевыми командами в функции ('Treeview' object has no attribute 'item, move" и тд.)
пример кода:

```
import sqlite3  # импорт модуля SQLite
import tkinter as tk  # импорт библиотеки tkinter
from tkinter import ttk  # импорт модуля TTk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()

    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    def init_main(self):  # главное окно
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)


        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage('')
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Добавить позицию', command=self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0,compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage('')
        btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Редактировать', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.update_img, compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_update_dialog)
        btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('id', 'prefix', 'number', 'postfix', 'zavod', 'quantity', 'cons_date', 'ubd_date'), height=15, show='headings')

        def treeview_sort_column(self, col, reverse):
            l = [(self.item(k)["text"], k) for k in self.get_children()]
            l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)

            for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
                self.move(k, '', index)

            self.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self, col, not reverse))

        self.tree.column('id', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('prefix', width=60, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('number', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('postfix', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('zavod', width=80, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('quantity', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('cons_date', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('ubd_date', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('id', text='ID', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'id', False))
        self.tree.heading('prefix', text='Префикс', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "prefix", False))
        self.tree.heading('number', text='Номенклатура', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "number", False))
        self.tree.heading('postfix', text='Суфикс', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "postfix", False))
        self.tree.heading('zavod', text='Завод', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "zavod", False))
        self.tree.heading('quantity', text='Ящ норма', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "quantity", False))
        self.tree.heading('cons_date', text='Дата консервации', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "cons_date", False))
        self.tree.heading('ubd_date', text='Дата введения', command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "ubd_date", False))

        self.tree.pack()
```

Пробую реализовать вот эту сортировку [Как реализовать сортировку в БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099775/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94), однако я, похоже, где-то ошибся и не вижу этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде вариант `treeview_sort_column` для сортировки по тексту из дерева (у вас дерево вообще отключено). Вам нужен вариант этой функции [из этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1100668). Также это отдельная функция, а не метод класса `Main`, поэтому не нужно пытаться вызывать ее как `self.treeview_sort_column(...)`, иначе будет сыпать ошибками `AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'treeview_sort_column'`. Т.к. это не метод, то и не нужно переименовывать первый параметр в `self`, а оставить как есть.

Рабочий пример:

```
import tkinter as tk  # импорт библиотеки tkinter
from tkinter import ttk  # импорт модуля TTk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        # self.db = db
        self.view_records()

    def view_records(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("",0,values=(i,))

    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    def init_main(self):  # главное окно
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        # self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage('')
        # btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Добавить позицию', command=self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0,compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        # btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage('')
        # btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Редактировать', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.update_img, compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_update_dialog)
        # btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('id', 'prefix', 'number', 'postfix', 'zavod', 'quantity', 'cons_date', 'ubd_date'), height=15, show='headings')

        def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
            l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
            l.sort(reverse=reverse)

            for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
                tv.move(k, '', index)

            tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))

        self.tree.column('id', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('prefix', width=60, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('number', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('postfix', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('zavod', width=80, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('quantity', width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('cons_date', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('ubd_date', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('id', text='ID', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'id', False))
        self.tree.heading('prefix', text='Префикс', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "prefix", False))
        self.tree.heading('number', text='Номенклатура', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "number", False))
        self.tree.heading('postfix', text='Суфикс', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "postfix", False))
        self.tree.heading('zavod', text='Завод', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "zavod", False))
        self.tree.heading('quantity', text='Ящ норма', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "quantity", False))
        self.tree.heading('cons_date', text='Дата консервации', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "cons_date", False))
        self.tree.heading('ubd_date', text='Дата введения', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "ubd_date", False))

        self.tree.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
Main(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

По поводу более естественной сортировки, изменяем функцию таким образом:

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse, key=str):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children()]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse, key=lambda t: key(t[0]))

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse, key=key))
```

Для числовых колонок в качестве параметра key передаем int (или float, если возможны дробные значения), для даты передаем функцию (в данном случае лябмда-функцию `lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%Y")` для даты формата `DD.MM.YYYY`, `datetime` импортируется как `from datetime import datetime`), конвертирующую дату в виде строки в объект даты, который потом нормально отсортируется при помощи `sort`. Для колонок со строковыми значениями можно ничего не передавать. Примеры:

```
self.tree.heading('id', text='ID', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, 'id', False, key=int))
self.tree.heading('prefix', text='Префикс', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "prefix", False))
self.tree.heading('number', text='Номенклатура', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "number", False))
self.tree.heading('postfix', text='Суфикс', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "postfix", False))
self.tree.heading('zavod', text='Завод', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "zavod", False))
self.tree.heading('quantity', text='Ящ норма', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "quantity", False, key=int))
self.tree.heading('cons_date', text='Дата консервации', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "cons_date", False, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%Y")))
self.tree.heading('ubd_date', text='Дата введения', command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(self.tree, "ubd_date", False, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%d.%m.%Y")))
```

Вообще, параметр `key` методов сортировки (`list.sort` или `sorted`) - это функция, которая применяется к каждому из сортируемых значений, по результатам выполнения этих функций в итоге выполняется сортировка. [Документация.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Для сортировки смешанных данных (числа внутри строк, например что-то вроде "Изображение 10") можно использовать модуль [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) (установка через `pip install natsort`)

Comment: Спасибо, я поразобрался, поправил - всё работает. Но работает не так, как я ожидал. В итоге эта функция сортирует данные как текст, то есть сначала сравнивает между собой первые символы строк, потом вторые и т.д.. Есть ли метод реализовать сортировку по `INT`, `DATE`, и т.д. не прибегая к постоянным запросам таблицы для вывода информации с помощью `ORDER BY` (Встроенная сортировка _SQLite_)

Comment: @СергейБелый для treeview_sort_column добавьте еще один параметр, в котором передавайте функцию, которая будет передаваться как параметр key в функцию sort: `l.sort(reverse=reverse, key=func)`. Для целочисленных колонок можно передавать просто int, для даты - функцию преобразования в объект [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), который уже будет сортироваться нормально.

Comment: @СергейБелый, я могу дополнить ответ с примером сортировки по числовым столбцами или столбцам с датой, если нужно. Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку слева от него).

Comment: было бы замечательно! И, если не сложно, можете сказать - где подробнее почитать про этот метод?
Галочку поставил, спасибо за указание

Comment: @СергейБелый дополнил ответ